# vb6: how to click buttons on another running process?

Tags: vb6

using vb6 is it possible to click buttons and forms on another running process programmatically ?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `SendMessage()` API call. This is what Windows itself uses to notify a button it has been clicked.

```
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
```

E.g. 
`retval = SendMessage(hwndButton, BM_CLICK, ByVal CLng(0), ByVal CLng(0))`

Tricky bit is getting the window handle of the button (`hwndButton`). `FindWindow()` and `EnumChildWindows()` APIs will do this. FindWindow() will return the handle of the top-level windows (e.g. Notepad). Then EnumChildWindows can be used to iterate the controls until the correct button is found.

Comment: +1. For finding the hWnd, I recommend Karl E Peterson's excellent VB6 code sample FindPart, which finds hWnds based on searching for the window caption. http://vb.mvps.org/samples/FindPart/